CORS issue when authorizing Twitter account with twitter-api-v2 in Node.js and React.js
I'm attempting to authorize a Twitter account using the twitter-api-v2 library in a Node.js API connected to a React.js frontend. Here's the Node.js code snippet I'm using:
const { TwitterApi } = require('twitter-api-v2');

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
    const twitterClient = new TwitterApi({
        appKey: process.env.TWITTER_APP_KEY,
        appSecret: process.env.TWITTER_APP_SECRET,
        accessToken: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
        accessSecret: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET,
        bearerToken: process.env.TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN
    });
    try {
        const { url, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret } = await twitterClient.generateAuthLink('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/twittercallback');
        req.session.oauth_token = oauth_token;
        req.session.oauth_token_secret = oauth_token_secret;
        res.redirect(url);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.json({
            status : 0,
            message : 'Error generating auth link',
            error : error
        })
    }
}

When I send a request to this API endpoint from my React.js app, the code executes correctly, but I encounter the following error upon redirection in the browser:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.x.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=CIpqTwAAAAABt-2-AAABkAJgN4U' (redirected from 'http://192.168.10.38:3000/api/v1/authtwitter') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Interestingly, when I send the request directly from the browser or Postman, everything works fine.
I'm unsure how to resolve this CORS issue. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
